# Struggling with TicTacToe in C

Tags: c, arrays, while-loop, console, tic-tac-toe

I tried to program a simple TicTacToe in C. The program itselfs compiles and show no errors.
So the program draws the field, reads the names and let a player put his symbol in a specific field. All this happens in a while loop, the should be run until its a draw or someone wins.
But the program just run the loop one time so there is only one turn then the program stops.

So here is my code:

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "game.h"


#define NAMELENGTH 20

 int main(void) {
char names[2][NAMELENGTH];
// field positions
char field[9];
int winner = -1;
getnames(names);
printf("\n\n");
initField(field);
// set field positions to 'empty'
char actualPlayer = (char)(get_random_number()*10.0) % 2;

while (1) {
    drawField(field);
    turn(actualPlayer, names, field);
    winner = isWinner(actualPlayer, field);
    drawField(field);
    if (winner >= 1) {
        printwinner(winner, names);
        return 0;
    }
    else if (winner == 0) {
        printDrawGame(names);
        return 0;
    }
    actualPlayer = (actualPlayer + 1) % 2;

}

return 0;

}
```

game.h Headerfile:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#define NAMELENGTH 20
#pragma warning(disable:4996)

extern void drawField(char *field);
extern void getnames(char nameField[][NAMELENGTH]);
extern void initField(char *field);
extern void turn(char actualPlayer, char names[][NAMELENGTH], char *field);
extern char isWinner(char actualPlayer, char *field);
extern void printwinner(char winnerNumber, char names[][NAMELENGTH]);
extern void printDrawGame(char names[][NAMELENGTH]);
extern double get_random_number();
```

and then my game.c where I defined my functions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "game.h"
#define NAMELENGTH 20
#pragma warning(disable:4996)

void drawField(char *field) {

printf("________________________\n");
printf("|       |       |      |\n");
printf("|   %c   |   %c   |   %c  |\n", field[0], field[1], field[2]);
printf("|_______|_______|______|\n");
printf("|       |       |      |\n");
printf("|   %c   |   %c   |   %c  |\n", field[3], field[4], field[5]);
printf("|_______|_______|______|\n");
printf("|       |       |      |\n");
printf("|   %c   |   %c   |   %c  |\n", field[6], field[7], field[8]);
printf("|_______|_______|______|\n");

}

void getnames(char nameField[][NAMELENGTH]) {

printf("Name of the first player: ");
scanf("%s", nameField[0]);
printf("Name of the second player: ");
scanf("%s", nameField[1]);

}

void initField(char *field) {

for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++)
{
    field[i] = i + '1';
}

}

void turn(char actualPlayer, char names[][NAMELENGTH], char *field) {

char symbol = ' ';
int p1fieldnumber;
int p2fieldnumber;


if (actualPlayer == 0)
{
    do {

        printf("\nIts Player %s's turn.", names[0]);
        char symbol = 'X';
        printf("\nNumber of the field which you want to put your symbol in: ");
        scanf("%d", &p1fieldnumber);
        if (field[p1fieldnumber] == 'X' || field[p1fieldnumber] == 'O')
        {
            printf("\nField is already occupied!");
            p1fieldnumber = 10;
        }
    } while (p1fieldnumber < 1 || p1fieldnumber > 9);

    field[p1fieldnumber-1] = 'X';

}
else {

    do {
        printf("\nIts Player %s's turn.", names[1]);
        char symbol = 'O';
        printf("\nNumber of the field which you want to put your symbol in: ");
        scanf("%d", &p2fieldnumber);
        if (field[p2fieldnumber] == 'X' || field[p2fieldnumber] == 'O')
        {
            printf("\nField is already occupied!");
            p2fieldnumber = 10;
        }
    } while (p2fieldnumber < 1 || p2fieldnumber > 9);

    field[p2fieldnumber-1] = 'O';

}

}

char isWinner(char actualPlayer, char *field) {

char pwinner = '3';

if (((field[0] == 'O') && (field[1] == 'O') && (field[2] == 'O')) || 
    (field[3] == 'O') && (field[4] == 'O') && (field[5] == 'O') || 
    (field[6] == 'O') && (field[7] == 'O') && (field[8] == 'O') || 
    (field[0] == 'O') && (field[4] == 'O') && (field[8] == 'O') || 
    (field[2] == 'O') && (field[4] == 'O') && (field[6] == 'O') || 
    (field[0] == 'O') && (field[3] == 'O') && (field[6] == 'O') ||
    (field[1] == 'O') && (field[4] == 'O') && (field[7] == 'O') || 
    (field[2] == 'O') && (field[5] == 'O') && (field[8] == 'O'))

{
    pwinner = '2';
}

else if (((field[0] == 'X') && (field[1] == 'X') && (field[2] == 'X')) || 
    (field[3] == 'X') && (field[4] == 'X') && (field[5] == 'X') || 
    (field[6] == 'X') && (field[7] == 'X') && (field[8] == 'X') || 
    (field[0] == 'X') && (field[4] == 'X') && (field[8] == 'X') || 
    (field[2] == 'X') && (field[4] == 'X') && (field[6] == 'X') || 
    (field[0] == 'X') && (field[3] == 'X') && (field[6] == 'X') || 
    (field[1] == 'X') && (field[4] == 'X') && (field[7] == 'X') || 
    (field[2] == 'X') && (field[5] == 'X') && (field[8] == 'X'))

{
    pwinner = '1';
}

else if (((field[0] == 'X') || (field[0] == 'O')) && ((field[1] == 'X') || (field[1] == 'O')) && ((field[2] == 'X') || (field[2] == 'O')) ||
    ((field[3] == 'X') || (field[3] == 'O')) && ((field[4] == 'X') || (field[4] == 'O')) && ((field[5] == 'X') || (field[5] == 'O')) ||
    ((field[6] == 'X') || (field[6] == 'O')) && ((field[7] == 'X') || (field[7] == 'O')) && ((field[8] == 'X') || (field[8] == 'O')) ||
    ((field[0] == 'X') || (field[0] == 'O')) && ((field[4] == 'X') || (field[4] == 'O')) && ((field[8] == 'X') || (field[8] == 'O')) ||
    ((field[2] == 'X') || (field[2] == 'O')) && ((field[4] == 'X') || (field[4] == 'O')) && ((field[6] == 'X') || (field[6] == 'O')) ||
    ((field[0] == 'X') || (field[0] == 'O')) && ((field[3] == 'X') || (field[3] == 'O')) && ((field[6] == 'X') || (field[6] == 'O')) ||
    ((field[1] == 'X') || (field[1] == 'O')) && ((field[4] == 'X') || (field[4] == 'O')) && ((field[7] == 'X') || (field[7] == 'O')) ||
    ((field[2] == 'X') || (field[2] == 'O')) && ((field[5] == 'X') || (field[5] == 'O')) && ((field[8] == 'X') || (field[8] == 'O')))
{
    pwinner = '0';
}

return pwinner;
}

void printwinner(char winnerNumber, char names[][NAMELENGTH]) {

if (winnerNumber == '1') {
    printf("Player %s won!", names[0]);
}
else if (winnerNumber == '2') {
    printf("Player %s won!", names[1]);
}

}

void printDrawGame(char names[][NAMELENGTH]) {
printf("Draw!");
}

static int _initialized;

double get_random_number() {
if (!_initialized) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    _initialized = 1;
}
return (double)rand() / ((double)(RAND_MAX)+1);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple issues

1. `isWinner` returns characters '0', '1', '2' and '3'. Replace them with numbers 0, 1, 2, 3, because your are comparing with numbers in `main`.
2. In `main` instead of checking `if (winner >= 1) {`, which is true even if 3 is returned by `isWinner`, check for `if (winner == 1 || winner == 2) {`.
3. Suggest to use parentheses in `isWinner` around each condition separated by `||`.

Parentheses as shown below for the first condition

```
if (((field[0] == 'O') && (field[1] == 'O') && (field[2] == 'O')) ||
    ((field[3] == 'O') && (field[4] == 'O') && (field[5] == 'O')) ||
    ((field[6] == 'O') && (field[7] == 'O') && (field[8] == 'O')) ||
    ((field[0] == 'O') && (field[4] == 'O') && (field[8] == 'O')) ||
    ((field[2] == 'O') && (field[4] == 'O') && (field[6] == 'O')) ||
    ((field[0] == 'O') && (field[3] == 'O') && (field[6] == 'O')) ||
    ((field[1] == 'O') && (field[4] == 'O') && (field[7] == 'O')) ||
    ((field[2] == 'O') && (field[5] == 'O') && (field[8] == 'O')))
```